# @jurisdiction not showing up in References When Using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to cite a court case with `biblatex-chicago`, but the reference is not showing up properly either in footnote or in References.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Saussure1995,
        Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
        Origyear = {1916},
        Publisher = {Payot},
        Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
        Year = {1995}}

    @book{Labov1972,
        Address = {Philadelphia},
        Author = {William Labov},
        Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
        Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
        Year = {1972}}  

    @jurisdiction{statevheckman,
        title={State v. Heckman},
        journaltitle={So},
        issue={2D06-5653},
        volume={993},
        pages={1004},
        date = {2007},
        location ={Court of Appeal of Florida, Second District}
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}


    \lipsum[1]\autocite{Saussure1995}

    \lipsum[2]\autocite{Labov1972}

    \lipsum[3]\autocite{statevheckman}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Your MWE does produce the footnote for me. The `@jurisdiction` entry does not appear in the bibliography unless I add `options={skipbib=false}` to the entry. This makes me suspect that `biblatex-chicago` is leaving this entry type out of the bibliography on purpose.

Comment: @DavidPurton That has to be the explanation, thank you for the note.

Comment: Bibliographies aren't much used in legal essays and judgments, hence a legal style guide is not really required. Unrelated: seeing legal authority mixed in with other material is strange; a separate list of cases might be more useful. If the intended audience is non-legal, expanding the doi-like legal reference (it should be `993 So. 2d 1004`) to `Southern Reporter, 2nd series, volume 993, page 1004` would help the reader locate the case. Although, these days, Google is a useful friend. The `2D06-5653` sounds like the publisher's internal reference number for a parts-publication method.

Answer (score 3):

You MWE does produce the footnote correctly for me (perhaps you had a typo somewhere).

For your bibliography issue, by default `biblatex-chicago` does not put `@jurisdiction` entry types into the bibliography.

From the manual:

> legalnotes=true
>
> This option prevents the printing of legal citations in a bibliography or
>   reference list, as the Bluebook recommends. You can change this to false in the
>   preamble of your document, but you should be aware that the reference printed in
>   the bibliography will be a clone of the long-note form, as the Bluebook doesn’t
>   provide an alternative version.

So, in theory, if you want all `@jurisdiction` entries to appear in your bibliography, then you would load `biblatex-chicago` like this:

```
\usepackage[natbib,isbn=false,legalnotes=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

In practice, this does not work because of a bug (I think) in `biblatex-chicago`.

So you can do one of two things:

1. You can add `options={skipbib=false}` to each of your `@jurisdiction` entries you want to appear in the bibliography, or
2. To put all legal entries into the bibliography, add this line just after you load `biblatex-chicago`:

   ```
   \ExecuteBibliographyOptions[jurisdiction,legal,legislation]{skipbib=false}
   ```